# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS no join display

Tags: 22.04

I am trying to duplicate screen between two of my monitors, but I do not see any such options.

Internet search shows "display" as a setting and have options for "Join Displays" or "mirros", but I do see such options.

Help please?

[image]

Comment: I don't know about using Wayland for this, but if you are using X you can use ARandR or XRandR to achieve mirroring.  See:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371793/how-to-duplicate-desktop-in-linux-with-xrandr